# I would like to sum all of the data in a specific table column, if the appropriate ID of that table exists in another one

Tags: sql-server

I would like to SUM a value called amount from table 1, the considered, to be summed, values should only be the ones presenting in table 2. Meaning that, for the amount of row 1 in table 1 to be considered in the sum. the ID of that row 1 should be present in table 2.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some example tables to help us visualize what you are talking about

Comment: Basically, it is Table 1 having many columns including ID and Number
Table 2 has many columns as well as the ID of table 1 as a FK
I would like to SUM all the numbers from the Number column of Table 1 but only when the corresponding ID exists in table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the answer but you really should have put some example tables in your example. I fancied helping as have 10 mins, this example you can run.
You can see that table 1 is referenced twice from Table2 and 3 just the once ,so the result ignores multiple occurrences, hence the WHERE EXISTS syntax.

This sums up all the numbers in Table1 that are referenced in Table2.

[image]

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

    CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
        Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        [Number] DECIMAL NOT NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #Table1 ([Number]) 
    VALUES('1'),
    ('1'), 
    ('1'), 
    ('1')

    SELECT * FROM #Table1

    CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
        Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        Table1Id INT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT FK_Table2_Table1 FOREIGN KEY (Table1Id) REFERENCES #Table1 (Id) 
    )

    INSERT INTO #Table2 ([Table1Id]) 
    VALUES('1'),
    ('1'), 
    ('3')

    SELECT * FROM #Table2

    SELECT SUM(T1.Number) AS SummedNumbersThatAreReferencedByTable2
    FROM #Table1 AS T1
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM #Table2 AS T2 
        WHERE T2.Table1Id = T1.Id
    )

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Rolling back changes, there was an error!!' 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(MAX)  
    SELECT @Msg=ERROR_MESSAGE() 
    RAISERROR('Error Occured: %s', 20, 101,@msg) WITH LOG
END CATCH
```

If this is the answer then please mark it as so, cheers